# Cannot read property 'ngMetadataName' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular-material-6

I am using Angular 6 with Angular Material. After updating to the latest version, the console is throwing this error in development. **On Production it is working**

`Cannot read property 'ngMetadataName' of undefined`

It occurs when I am trying to open material dialog via a service ( without a service they are working fine). I think it is related to the Injectables, but I am not sure.

**Versions: cli: 6.1.5 , core: 6.1.4, material: 6.4.6**

Here is the log stack:

```
CustomDialogComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngMetadataName' of undefined
at injectArgs (core.js:1418)
at core.js:1491
at _callFactory (core.js:8438)
at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8396)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8371)
at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:9064)
at PortalInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/portal.es5.js.PortalInjector.get (portal.es5.js:732)
at resolveDep (core.js:9419)
at createClass (core.js:9309)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9186)
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

dialog inside the service, where the error is thrown :

```
 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class customService {
  constructor(private store: Store<RootState>, private dialog: MatDialog) {}

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(customDialogComponent, {
  width: '300px',
  data: {
    loading: false,
    customId,
  }
});
```

Comment: mention the versions of @angular/cdk, @angular/core and @angular/material that you're using/

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera , added.

Comment: i got the same error because in defined two services in one file while the first service in file was using the second one as DI (which was not defined at this time because is declared after the first one)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Same message but no relation with Material, I had this error too. I realized, there is a warning about circular dependency. This error disappears after I remove dependencies.

May be other warning messages during compile process will help to fix this.

To see the created circular dependency in your angular project, please enable `showCircularDependencies` in `angular.json` by changing its value from `false` to `true`.

Comment: I recommend grabbing the circular dependency plugin for webpack, that showed us a bunch of circular deps, that, when fixed, cause the above error to go away: https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin

Comment: Same happened with me

Answer (score 19):

I encountered this error when I upgraded Angular with the CLI version 8.0.4. 
I had to downgrade to `@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.800.3` and Angular CLI to version `8.0.3`.

```sh
npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.800.3 @angular/cli@8.0.3
```

Comment: This solved my problem too. Not sure why tho. Do you have any theory about why this happens on 8.0.4? I also found out that using this version, Angular was complaining at runtime about a missing interface declared in the same file.

Comment: I've read on angular GitHub issues that it was corrected on the following nightly build. I guess we just gotta wait for the next release. I have no idea why it happens though.

Comment: @GabrielG. Did not test it but I think this happens when you have @Inject(..) decorator and defined the type of the parameter at the same time.

Comment: @GökhanKurt can you explain more what exactly causes this? I was running into it with Inject but couldn't figure out why it would sometimes happen. Would really like to generate an example.

Comment: I had this error in CLI `8.0.6` and the downgrade to `8.0.3` fixed it for me.

Comment: FYI Issue closed https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f83dfd6f5aabdfc1c5363fa8a7f7b8145c8fad92

Comment: Any idea why this issue was closed?

Comment: It's fixed in the latest 8.1.0

Comment: More info about the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14888#issuecomment-508096612

Answer (score 3):

I had this error due to having 2 services in 1 file. Moving them to separate files solved the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was just because the classes were `@Injectable`, not necessarily a service.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading @angular/core to 6.0.0

Here is a [Sample StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal) to help you out with the versions of different packages. There are quite a lot of issues with the version mismatch due to which these errors occur.

Here are a few other configs to keep in mind that work well with each other:

```
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "6.4.6"
```

Comment: No Luck. Actually the modals are opening normally, the only problem is when i am opening the modal through a Service. The injectables are causing the error.

Comment: Okay. Create a stackbliz and probably someone will have a look into it. There might be some issues with the syntax only it seems.

Comment: Also, on Production it works, its just with the development.

Comment: Moved back to an older image, its working. Thanks for the help. But i will still wait for other answers to solve the issue.

Comment: You can put the v7.2.2. It is stable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476229/typeerror-unable-to-get-property-ngmetadataname-of-undefined-or-null-referenc/55165724#55165724

Answer (score 1):

Check a few things ..

1>Check all the User Defined Services are registered under **app.module.ts** providers[]

2>All the Angular Modules(eg.AppRoutingModule,FormsModule,HttpClientModule) should be registered under imports[]

It has resolved my issue .

Comment: This is solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in my Angular 7 project.

```
constructor(private worksheetHandler: WorksheetPayloadHandler,
    private worksheetRepository: WorksheetRepository) { }
```

As user3102108 mentioned the issue was because there was a circular dependency detected. To confirm, you can run `ng build` and check the warnings in the terminal. I was getting the warning as below.

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\modules\service\services\worksheets\worksheet.events.service.ts -> src\modules\service\services\worksheets\worksheet.repository.ts -> src\modules\service\services\worksheets\worksheet.events.service.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\modules\service\services\worksheets\worksheet.repository.ts -> src\modules\service\services\worksheets\worksheet.events.service.ts -> src\modules\service\services\worksheets\worksheet.repository.ts
```

After removing the circular dependency, the issue was resolved.

Comment: For my case circular dependency was the problem, but `ng build` did'n give any useful information

Answer (score 0):

Last time I `ng serve` 'd, a message prompted saying

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
```

Took advice but then, an error prompted saying that I needed to first command `yarn install`.

After that, a warning about mixing lockfiles.

I ended up just npm updating and installing and ignoring the initial warning message.

The other recommended option, if you are still willing to use the newest angular,
is to use with `ng serve --aot.`

Answer (score 0):

There might be a circular dependency in your code.

solve it, This error will go.