# TypeError: Unable to get property 'ngMetadataName' of undefined or null reference on IE 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, polyfills

In IE 10, I got the following error: (but OK in IE 11)

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'ngMetadataName' of undefined or null reference

The property `ngMetadataName` has been found in `vendor.js`.

The ***polyfills.ts*** is as the following:

```
  /******************************************************************************* 

BROWSER POLYFILLS
*/
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js'; // Run npm install --save classlist.js.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**

Web Animations @angular/platform-browser/animations
Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
**/
import 'web-animations-js'; // Run npm install --save web-animations-js.
/**

By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
*/
// (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
// (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
// (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

/*

in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
with the following flag, it will bypass zone.js patch for IE/Edge
*/
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
/***************************************************************************************************

Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
*/
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
/***************************************************************************************************

APPLICATION IMPORTS
*/
```

Can you please suggest how to resolve this for IE 10.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24339. Refer this link

Comment: Thanks @Suresh Kumar Ariya .
It is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the **angular-cli** from 6.0.8 to 6.2.3 (Latest) and it solved the above error.

This link [github#24339](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24339) might be helpful.

Thanks to @Suresh Kumar Ariya

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with the components that needs to be declared in **entryComponents**. The angular ~7.2.2 upper version are broken these components.

1. First of all, I recommend to remove all **^** and **~** to maintaining a stable application version.
2. The stable version of angular 7 packages is **7.2.2**. So put version 7.2.2 for all *@angular/package_name* on *package.json*

   ```
   "@angular/cli "7.2.2",
   "@angular/compiler "7.2.2",
   "@angular/compiler-cli "7.2.2",
   "@angular/language-service "7.2.2",
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade @angular/cli (and associated packages) to version 7.2.9 or higher should fix this.

`npm install @angular/cli@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/language-service@latest`